# Mongo - query for documents in range of date and also the nearest one to this range

Tags: mongodb

I want to query mongo for documents in date range and also I want to get nerest one but outside of this range. For example:
Documents in db:

```
{id: 1, dDate: 2024.01.10}
{id: 2, dDate: 2024.01.11}
{id: 3, dDate: 2024.01.22}
{id: 4, dDate: 2024.01.23}
{id: 5, dDate: 2024.01.24}
{id: 6, dDate: 2024.01.30}
{id: 7, dDate: 2024.01.31}
```

I want to query for dates - **gte: 2024.01.22 and lte: 2024.01.24**
and in a result I want to receive documents:

```
{id: 2, dDate: 2024.01.11}
{id: 3, dDate: 2024.01.22}
{id: 4, dDate: 2024.01.23}
{id: 5, dDate: 2024.01.24}
{id: 6, dDate: 2024.01.30}
```

so basicity I want to get documents in range and also the nearest one (in the both sides) to this range

Answer (score 0):

1. `$facet` - Allow multiple pipelines to be executed in an aggregate query.

   1.1. "inRange" - Get the document with `dDate` within the search date range.

   1.2. "beforeRange" - Get the first matching document with `dDate` is before the starting search date range.

   1.3. "afterRange" - Get the first matching document with `dDate` is after the ending search date range.
2. `$set` - Add the `docs` field by combining the three array fields into a single array.
3. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `docs` array field into multiple documents.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with the `docs` object.
5. `$sort` - Order the document by the `dDate` field ascending.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      inRange: [
        {
          $match: {
            dDate: {
              $gte: ISODate("2024-01-22"),
              $lte: ISODate("2024-01-24")
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      beforeRange: [
        {
          $match: {
            dDate: {
              $lt: ISODate("2024-01-22")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            dDate: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      afterRange: [
        {
          $match: {
            dDate: {
              $gt: ISODate("2024-01-24")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            dDate: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      docs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$beforeRange",
          "$inRange",
          "$afterRange"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      dDate: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3mG-XyYE-sW)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$setWindowFields` to get the previous and next date for each entry. Afterwards, you can decide whether a document should be included in the result by checking whether any of the dates is in your range:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "dDate": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "prev": {
          "$first": "$dDate",
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              -1,
              -1
            ]
          }
        },
        "next": {
          "$first": "$dDate",
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              1,
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      include: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: [
                  "$dDate",
                  "$prev",
                  "$next"
                ],
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        "$$this",
                        ISODate("2024-01-22T00:00:00Z")
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        "$$this",
                        ISODate("2024-01-24T00:00:00Z")
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      include: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "include",
      "next",
      "prev"
    ]
  }
])
```

Above aggregation pipeline first sets the `prev` and `next` fields to the corresponding dates; then it adds a temporary field `include` that is set to `true` if the document should be included in the output. After filtering the documents with a `$match` stage, the temporary fields are removed from the documents so that the result is ready:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "dDate": ISODate("2024-01-11T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "dDate": ISODate("2024-01-22T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "dDate": ISODate("2024-01-23T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "dDate": ISODate("2024-01-24T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "dDate": ISODate("2024-01-30T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

You can check the [mongoplayground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHwPvU5eb3k).

The pipeline can be optimized a bit by checking the include-condition directly in the match and omitting the temporary field; however, I hope that the query engine is able to sort this out. I've kept the field for demonstration purposes.

Sorting the data is necessary only once during the `$setWindowFields` stage.